# java: how to limit score results in mongo

Tags: text-search

I have this mongo query (java):

```
TextQuery.queryText(textCriteria).sortByScore().limit(configuration.getSearchResultSize())
```

which performs a text search and sort by score.
I gave different wiehgt to different fields in the docuemnt, and now I'd like to retrieve only those results with score lower then 10.

is there a way to add that criteria to the query?

this didn't work:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("score").lt(10));
```

if the only way is to use aggregation - I need a mongoTemplate example for that.

**in other words**

how the do I translate the following mongo shell aggregate command, to java spring's mongoTemplate command??
can't find anywhere how to use the aggregate's match() API with the $text search component (the $text is indexed on several different fields):

```
db.text.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { $text: { $search: "read" } } },
     { $project: { title: 1, score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
     { $match: { score: { $lt: 10.0 } } }
   ]
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shemerk, Accept the answer if you feel the answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below code sample, MongoDB search with pagination code in java

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject()
query.put(column_name, new BasicDBObject("$regex", searchString).append("$options", "i"));
DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
cursor.skip((pageNum-1)*limit);
cursor.limit(limit);
```

Write a loop and and call the above code from loop and pass the values like **pageNum** starts from 1 to n and **limit** depends on your requirement. check the cursor is empty or not. If empty skip the loop if not continue calling the above code base.

Hope this will be helpful.